# Prime Ng Calendar triggering a page reload

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, primeng

I am using [primeng calendar component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) with angular 2. The problem I am facing is whenever I select the time from it. It triggers a complete roundtrip (whole page reload) and I loose all the data on the page. Not able to solve it event after trying a lot to search something related to this issue.

```
 <td [(hidden)]="item.fullDay">
    <p-calendar placeholder="Start Time" [(ngModel)]="item.startTime" showTime="true" [disabled]="isReadOnly" timeOnly="true" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></p-calendar>
 </td>
```

I do not want to put any other button to click and do only one way binding, simply because the use case doesn't permit it. Below is what I am trying to achieve and selection of time shouldn't trigger the round trip.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by roundtrip ? Can you create a Plunker maybe ?

Comment: Round trip means it reloads the whole page.

Comment: Did you check if you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Without more code, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: @SemirDeljić - There is no error in console.

Comment: @Antikhippe - What else do you need, please let me know I will share.

Comment: Do you use PrimeNg version which depends on jQuery?

Comment: @Jeet Please share your component HTML and TS code

Comment: @SemirDeljić - Yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was manipulation of the field which I was trying to bind. In this case I was trying to achieve two way binding with the field `item.startTime` and I was calculating this field by `item.startTime = new Date(someDate).getTime()` as soon as I removed `.getTime` from the expression It All worked well.